# react-native-gesture-handler not working in release apk

Tags: android, react-native

I have used [react-native-draggable-flatlist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-flatlist) in my react-native app which depends on react-native-gesture-handler. Out of nowhere my app started crashing on launch, I figured from logs that it was this [migration process](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/guides/migrating-off-rnghenabledroot) I have to follow. Accordingly I wrapped my app with GestureHandlerRootView and now it works perfectly in the debug variant, but in the release variant the drag gesture stopped working and it doesn't give any error at all.
What am I doing wrong?